# Erro em JSON com índice Alfabético

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho 2 **Arrays**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amit
            [1] => amit@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rahul
            [1] => rahul@example.com
        )

)
```

e

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProdutosidProduto] => 1
            [Produtostipo] => mp
            [Produtosmodelo] => F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60
            [Produtosbandejas] => 2
            [Produtospeso] => 0
            [Produtosprensagem] => 0
            [ProdutosprecoUnitario] => 6500
            [Produtoscomprimento] => 100
            [Produtoslargura] => 60
            [Produtoscabo] => 0
            [Produtosligacao] => n
            [Produtospotencia] => 0
            [Produtosconsumo] => 0
            [Produtoscorrente] => 0
            [Produtosdisjuntor] => 0
            [Produtosdescricao] => 
Valor promocional limitado frete grátis ,para SP ,RJ ,MG ,ES. Os demais será cobrado apenas de SP para sua cidade ,valor de 500,00 ,a ser pago na entrega .

MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 
            [Produtosestoque] => 7
            [ProdutosfreteGratis] => s
            [Produtosbloqueado] => n
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ProdutosidProduto] => 2
            [Produtostipo] => mp
            [Produtosmodelo] => F540 2 BAN.PNEU.80X100 A VISTA BOLETO PAGSEGURO
            [Produtosbandejas] => 2
            [Produtospeso] => 190
            [Produtosprensagem] => 300
            [ProdutosprecoUnitario] => 7500
            [Produtoscomprimento] => 70
            [Produtoslargura] => 100
            [Produtoscabo] => 6
            [Produtosligacao] => b
            [Produtospotencia] => 7500
            [Produtosconsumo] => 3
            [Produtoscorrente] => 35
            [Produtosdisjuntor] => 40
            [Produtosdescricao] => MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 
www.topuhrens.de


            [Produtosestoque] => 8
            [ProdutosfreteGratis] => n
            [Produtosbloqueado] => n
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ProdutosidProduto] => 3
            [Produtostipo] => mp
            [Produtosmodelo] => (PROMOÇÃO )2 BAN.PNEU.80X100, VALOR PROMOCIONAL .
            [Produtosbandejas] => 2
            [Produtospeso] => 200
            [Produtosprensagem] => 300
            [ProdutosprecoUnitario] => 8990
            [Produtoscomprimento] => 80
            [Produtoslargura] => 100
            [Produtoscabo] => 6
            [Produtosligacao] => b
            [Produtospotencia] => 7500
            [Produtosconsumo] => 3
            [Produtoscorrente] => 35
            [Produtosdisjuntor] => 40
            [Produtosdescricao] => MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE replica watches for sale A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 

CONSUMO : 3 KW/H 

            [Produtosestoque] => 97
            [ProdutosfreteGratis] => n
            [Produtosbloqueado] => n
        )
```

Desejo transformá-los em **JSON** porém *respeitando* seus *índices*.

Com o primeiro **Array** fiz:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($myArr); ?>;
```

com o segundo fiz:

```
var res = <?php echo json_encode($produtos); ?>;
```

Bom, quando fui conferir o **JSON** que saiu, verifiquei que

Para o primeiro **Array** temos que:

```
document.write(arr[1][0]) => imprimiu Rahul;
```

Para o segundo **Array**, temos que:

```
document.write(res[0]["ProdutosidProduto"]) => Imprimiu undefined;
```

Mas quando fiz:

```
document.write(res) => imprimiu [object Object],[object Object]
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Se os **Arrays** são quase idênticos, onde está o erro?

Será fato de que um tem **índices** como ***palavras*** e outro ***índices numéricos***?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Testando aqui , deu certo da seguinte forma:

```
    <?php
$arr2=array(
    0=>"aa"
);
$arr1=Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'ProdutosidProduto' => 1,
            'Produtostipo' => 3,
            'Produtosmodelo' => 'F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60',
            'Produtosbandejas' => 2,
            'Produtospeso' => 0,
            'Produtosprensagem' => 0,
            'ProdutosprecoUnitario' => 6500,
            'Produtoscomprimento' => 100,
            'Produtoslargura' => 60,
            'Produtoscabo' => 0,
            'Produtosligacao' => 'n',
            'Produtospotencia' => 0,
            'Produtosconsumo' => 0,
            'Produtoscorrente' => 0,
            'Produtosdisjuntor' => 0,
            'Produtosdescricao' => 'Valor promocional limitado frete grátis ,para SP ,RJ ,MG ,ES. Os demais será cobrado apenas de SP para sua cidade ,valor de 500,00 ,a ser pago na entrega .

MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. ',
            'Produtosestoque' => 7,
            'ProdutosfreteGratis' => 's',
            'Produtosbloqueado' => 'n'
        ),

        1 => Array
        (
            'ProdutosidProduto' => 1,
            'Produtostipo' => 3,
            'Produtosmodelo' => 'F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60',
            'Produtosbandejas' => 2,
            'Produtospeso' => 0,
            'Produtosprensagem' => 0,
            'ProdutosprecoUnitario' => 6500,
            'Produtoscomprimento' => 100,
            'Produtoslargura' => 60,
            'Produtoscabo' => 0,
            'Produtosligacao' => 'n',
            'Produtospotencia' => 0,
            'Produtosconsumo' => 0,
            'Produtoscorrente' => 0,
            'Produtosdisjuntor' => 0,
            'Produtosdescricao' => 'Valor promocional limitado frete grátis ,para SP ,RJ ,MG ,ES. Os demais será cobrado apenas de SP para sua cidade ,valor de 500,00 ,a ser pago na entrega .

MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. ',
            'Produtosestoque' => 7,
            'ProdutosfreteGratis' => 's',
            'Produtosbloqueado' => 'n'
        ));

        $json = json_encode($arr1);
?>

<script>
var json=<?php echo $json; ?>;
document.write(json[0]['ProdutosidProduto']);
</script>
```

Se o problema persistir, sugiro que vc depure com um var_dump antes de enviar o json para o destino, veja se a estrutura das chaves continuam integras

Comment: Estou fazendo o seguinte: Estou tendo um retorno de uma Query SQL. Com essa Query, monto um Array de objetos (sim, todos do mesmo tipo). pós isso, estou gerando em um foreach um novo array com cada objeto convertido em Array (array) $todos. Esse ´é o array que está na pergunta. Agora preciso transformá-lo em um JSon

Comment: Pois é, perceba que o teu é 'ProdutosidProduto' e o meu é [ProdutosidProduto]. O seu vem dentro de aspas '' e o meu dentro de colchetes [].e não estou sabendo como tratar isso

Comment: Sim , de fato notei que as estruturas dos arrays são diferentes, no seu caso, como foi construida?
Da forma que montei foi um dos padrões PHP

Comment: é apenas um retorno de um método comum publico que entrega uma SQL Query no MYSQL com mysql_fetch_row(). mysqli: $registros->fetch_row(). Daí pego esse retorno e dei um PRINT_R() nele! Só isso